# Magento Connect not showing list of packages?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have magento `1.5.1.0`.  Now I want to upgrade it to `magento 1.7.2.0`, but when I go to `magento connect manager` it doesn't show list of packages installed. I have applied so many things but it didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote all your code properly (didn't overwrite any core files, didn't put your template in the base folder), you should do a manual upgrade. [Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/manual_upgrade_using_fresh_install_and_original_database) you will find all the information you need (basically you copy a fresh 1.7 install over your site).

Most important thing: make a back-up before attempting an upgrade.

After the upgrade, set the permissions again then check your logs to see if there are any errors.

Comment: But even than i have to repair magento connect for future use.

Comment: Usually these upgrades fix most, if not all the problems you have before. You'll have new problems though, but that's how upgrades work :)

Comment: I have tried uploading fresh magento downloader folder but this problem still exist.